# Why are resolution and Hilbert with Mendelson's axioms correct and sound proof systems?

Tags: logic

Let $\Gamma$ be an alphabet, with $\Gamma*$ being the set of strings over $\Gamma$.
Let $L$ be a language over $\Gamma$, in other words $L⊂\Gamma∗$.

A proof system for $L$ is a polynomial time computable partial function $f:\Gamma∗\rightarrow \Gamma∗$ with range $L$. The size $\vert\pi\vert$ of a proof $\vert\pi\vert$ in $Γ∗$ is the number of characters it contains.

Proof system $f$ maps a proof to the theorem it proves (or refutes, in the case of a refutational proof system). Soundness of $f$ requires that $rng(f)⊆L$ and completeness that $rng(f)⊇L.$

Why are resolution and Hilbert with Mendelson's axioms correct and sound proof systems in the sense mentioned above, how would one specify the functions $f$ for these systems?

Comment: We prove it: Completeness Theorem.

Comment: It means that a suitable choice of axioms+rules give us the logical resources that are enough to prove all (and only) valid formulas.

Comment: This is shown by Cook and Reckhow in [The Relative Efficiency of Propositional Proof Systems](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273702).

Comment: This seems to be a very strange view on what a proof system should be. What has polynomial time got to do with logical soundness or correctness. Can you provide a reference for your definition of a proof system.